# How to read http headers of last response?

Tags: javascript

I am adding a custom `HTTP header` to a `204 - no content` response in `PHP`:

```
header("Success: true");
http_response_code(204);
```

Question is how can I then read this header in `JavaScript`?

Edit:
Should have mentioned this is for the current page not an Ajax request.
From what I can establish there is no way to access http headers from within Javascript so it looks like this is not possible.

Comment: No the header of the current page

Comment: What page is there when there's no content? Without content, no page, no Javascript.

Comment: 204 (no content) response

Comment: Should have explained in a bit more detail.  A form can be submitted using either Javascript ({form}.submit()) or even a standard html form submit, that form can then be saved on the server and the server can return an http 204 (no content) response.  That way the current page is not replaced with the response.